# Oracle ArrayBound Stored Procedure fails only with specific field

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, ado.net, odp.net

I have a stored procedure that works and has been working for months for inserting data.

Here's the "short" version:

```
procedure saveApplication(  in_confirmation_number  varchar2 := null                           
                            ,in_nonstandard_address varchar2 := null      
                            ,in_absentee_type varchar2 := null) AS
  BEGIN
    insert into vr_application (
            confirmation_number
            ,nonstandard_address
            ,absentee_type )
    values ( in_confirmation_number
            ,in_nonstandard_address
            ,in_absentee_type 
            );
END;
```

I'm working in bulk so I stuff the data in as arrays after pulling the value from a datatable.
Again, below is the "shortened" version.

```
private static void loadFiles(DataTable dt, string connString, ErrorLogger log)
    {

        OracleConnection orclconn = null;
        OracleCommand cmd = null;

        using (orclconn = new OracleConnection(connString))
        {
            orclconn.Open();
            using (cmd = BuildCommand(dt))
            {
                cmd.Connection = orclconn;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

    }

 private static OracleCommand BuildCommand(DataTable dt)
    {
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "Applications.saveApplication";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.ArrayBindCount = dt.Rows.Count;
        cmd.BindByName = true;

        string[] CONFIRMATION_NUMBER = dt
           .AsEnumerable()
           .Select(row => row.Field<string>("CONFIRMATION_NUMBER"))
           .ToArray();
        OracleParameter in_confirmation_number = new OracleParameter();
        in_confirmation_number.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
        in_confirmation_number.Value = CONFIRMATION_NUMBER;
        in_confirmation_number.ParameterName = "in_confirmation_number";
        cmd.Parameters.Add(in_confirmation_number);

         string[] ABSENTEE_TYPE = dt
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(row => row.Field<string>("ABSENTEE_TYPE"))
            .ToArray();
        OracleParameter in_absentee_type = new OracleParameter();
        in_absentee_type.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
        in_absentee_type.Value = ABSENTEE_TYPE;
        in_absentee_type.ParameterName = "in_absentee_type";
        cmd.Parameters.Add(in_absentee_type);

        string[] NONSTANDARD_ADDRESS = dt
         .AsEnumerable()
         .Select(row => row.Field<string>("NONSTANDARD_ADDRESS"))
         .ToArray();
        OracleParameter in_nonstandard_address = new OracleParameter();
        in_absentee_type.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
        in_absentee_type.Value = NONSTANDARD_ADDRESS;
        in_absentee_type.ParameterName = "in_nonstandard_address";
        cmd.Parameters.Add(in_nonstandard_address);

        return cmd;
}
```

**Scenario 1:**
nonstandard_address code is commented out.  Everything works.

**Scenario 2:**
nonstandard_address code is not commented out.  But instead of passing values into the original datatable, I hardcode the value "null".  Everything works.  This is where it has been for months.

**Scenario 3:**
the datatable for nonstandard address has a single row which has a value in nonstandard address.  All other rows contain null for this column.  I get an Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException, #ORA-06550, with the message "Encountered the symbol ">" when expecting one of the following...."

To attempt to identify the problem, I simply looped through the values in the array.  I get the same error on the last loop iteration, which is always one more than the number of records in the data table (100).  But if I loop without attempting to create an Oracle Parameter for nonstandard, I get no error and only 100 loop iterations.

If I do Scenario 2 and successfully fill the table with everything except nonstandard_address, I can then run the following in Oracle, and successfully update the table.

```
update vr_application a
set nonstandard_address = (select nonstandard_address from unprocessed_apps b where b.confirmation_number = a.confirmation_number)
where exists (select 1 from unprocessed_apps where confirmation_number = a.confirmation_number)
```

Can anyone see a mistake here?  Anyone seen this before?  I'm baffled.

Comment: Try putting the code for the nonstandard_address parameter before the code for absentee_type, in order to specify the parameters in the same order they're named in the PL/SQL procedure.  I don't think this should matter but it's worth a shot.

Comment: worth a try - I'll be working on this later today and will let you know the outcome.

Comment: moving it wasn't the answer, but it gave me the answer because of a compile error.  and now I feel stupid.  But I guess after updating 72 fields the eyes get fuzzy.  Look at my variable names - I used in_absentee_type as the variable to receive the nonstandard address.  This, of course, means the value doesn't fit in the field.  The Oracle error was a bit misleading.  Thank you for leading me to the right solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it was one of those "duh" moments and a good argument for having coworkers who can be an extra set of eyes.

Look at my code - I fed the address into the absentee field.  This is what I had:

```
    string[] NONSTANDARD_ADDRESS = dt
     .AsEnumerable()
     .Select(row => row.Field<string>("NONSTANDARD_ADDRESS"))
     .ToArray();
    OracleParameter in_nonstandard_address = new OracleParameter();
    **in_absentee_type**.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
    **in_absentee_type**.Value = NONSTANDARD_ADDRESS;
    **in_absentee_type**.ParameterName = "in_nonstandard_address";
    cmd.Parameters.Add(in_nonstandard_address);
```

This is what I SHOULD have had:

```
       string[] NONSTANDARD_ADDRESS = dt
           .AsEnumerable()
           .Select(row => row.Field<string>("NONSTANDARD_ADDRESS"))
           .ToArray();
        OracleParameter in_nonstandard_address = new OracleParameter();
        **in_nonstandard_address**.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
        **in_nonstandard_address**.Value = NONSTANDARD_ADDRESS;
        **in_nonstandard_address**.ParameterName = "in_nonstandard_address";
        cmd.Parameters.Add(in_nonstandard_address);
```

After staring at 72 arrays like the above, my eyes just totally missed it.  Thanks to Bob Jarvis for suggesting something that made the syntax problem pop out at me.